# Visio the standard for software development sketching?

Tags: diagram, visio

I feel that my professional exposure has been biased towards Visio, by the choice of IT managers and project managers. I've worked only in Microsoft solution centric shops where MS Office was the standard.

Are there any other professional shops out there using other tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the current star product for ***user interface prototyping*** is Balsamiq Mockups:

http://balsamiq.com/products/mockups

Another new and good choice is FlairBuilder:

http://www.flairbuilder.com/

Another similar tool is ForeUI:

http://www.foreui.com/

Comment: This is a great tool I also use, but obviously it can't do diagrams.

Comment: Balsamiq doesn't have very much in the way of UML modeling, however.

Comment: I love Balsamiq, we've begun using it for all of our mockups. It has the added benefit of not being too detailed, and thus having the business people latch on to a look.

Comment: balsamiq ++

I find that doing tons of diagraming for processes is a crutch. When we hit a domain language that works for the user, everything can be done on a napkin and then is self documenting.

Answer (score 9):

A whiteboard is pretty good. Bad upgrade path though.

Comment: @Patrick ... lmao. I think dia should get more dev-time really. Could be better.

Comment: Whiteboard + Cellphone Camera -> Email photo -> Print photo -> Set on wooden table -> Arrange multiple photos on the table until diagram is made -> Take another digital photo and email -> Clean up some in photoshop -> Save in diagrams folder.

Comment: @TheTXI -- Why aren't you patenting that! Quick, go go go. :P

Comment: @Aiden Bell - Whiteboard: pretty easy learning curve, though you might have a little problem with font displaying nicely at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I either use my whiteboard, or a nifty little Free Software tool called [UMLPad](http://web.tiscali.it/ggbhome/umlpad/umlpad.htm).

It would be really nifty if there was a nice standard vector drawing file format so that these tools could interoperate. SVG is close, but IE doesn't support it. In the meantime UMLPad does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html) by Sparx Systems is very popular. I have used it at several places I have worked.

Answer (score 0):

UModel is a very good diagramming tool which I prefer greatly over Visio.

Rational Rose is another major player in the diagramming and modeling world.

Both of these products above generally will be more expensive than Visio, making them not as widely used in all software development circles. There are also lots of smaller and pretty popular free alternatives out there like UMLPad.

Visio is only the most widely used because it is the one people tend to gravitate towards through their Microsoft Office familiarity, not generally because it's the best product out there (far from it in my opinion). I wouldn't call it a standard other than maybe a de facto standard due to its high numbers.

Comment: Rational Rose is awful, IMO. I used to HATE working with it.

Comment: unforgiven3: I was not a fan of RR myself, but it was something I was forced to use for my software engineering courses in university.

Comment: Rational Rose has an interface that didn't change from Windows 3.1 era. But it can do nice UML...

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Smartdraw](http://www.smartdraw.com/) during my college time and I really like it,but at the company I work we use all Microsoft stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about UML diagrams, I've not worked professionally with any, but I find different free diagramming are good for different diagrams.

I prefer
ArgoUML for class diagrams, sequence diagrams
UMLet for deployment and component diagrams
Dia for activity diagrams

That covers the diagrams I spend most of my time drawing.

I find UMLet and Dia are easy to use and put together nearly all diagrams I'd need, and ArgoUML has additional features that help with specific diagrams, and also provides code generation from class diagrams.

I've also used Borland Together, and also it's round robin features are nice, I found it really hard to work with unless you used it the way the Borland intended you, which often becomes fustrating

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [Lovely Charts](http://my.lovelycharts.com/), if your doing something pretty light weight, their free version *might* work out for you.

For flow charts, I love [bubbl.us](http://bubbl.us/)

Both of these are in flash.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to ForeUI, switching themes + DHTML interactive simulation, really powerful and handy.